# How to speed up binary search using some extra information about range

Tags: c++, algorithm, binary-search

I have a game, which is played in the following manner :

- The game starts with displaying me a time in `<h>:<m>:<s>:<ms>` format
- Next i take a guess less than or equal to the one printed previously and enter it.
- The game displays one of the following based on my time

  Platinum 
  Gold
  Stone
- Repeat from step 2.

It is basically like a race , the time is finishing time of the race and i get Platinum for best(lowest) time and stone for the worst(greater) time. Please note the starting time given by the game is largest time required for `Stone`.

I need to get the **Largest** time for which i can get `Platinum`.

So i implimented a binary search algorithm , which halves the interval of time where the required value of time lies. Simply :

```
low = mid + 1; // if i get platinum 
high = mid - 1; // otherwise
```

Here is the complete code:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<algorithm>
#include<vector>
#include<stdio.h>


using namespace std;

class times
{
public:
int h,m,s,ms;
int mili;

times ()
{
    h = m=s=ms =0;
    mili = 0;
}


times(int a,int b,int c,int d)
{
    h = a,m=b,s=c,ms=d;
    make();
}


void bake( ) //do reverse of make() for given mili
{
    long int x = mili;
    ms = x%1000;
    x /= 1000;
    s = x%60;
    x/= 60;
    m = x%60;
    x /= 60;

}


void make()  // calc total mili based on cur val of h,m,s and ms
{
    mili = ms;
    mili += s*1000 + m*60*1000 + h*3600*1000;
}


};

int main()
{
int h,m,s,msl;
bool flag;
string str;
    scanf("%d:%d:%d:%d",&h,&m,&s,&msl);

    times mid(h,m,s,msl);
    int low=0,high;
    high = mid.mili;

    while( low < high )
    {
        mid.mili = (high+low)/2;
        mid.bake();
        printf("%d:%02d:%02d:%03d" , mid.h , mid.m,mid.s,mid.ms );
        fflush(stdout); //FLUSH

        cin>>str; // the relic

        if(str=="PLATINUM") // we have more time than req
            {
                low = mid.mili+1;
                flag = true;
            }
        else
            {
                high = mid.mili-1;
                flag = false;
            }


    }
    if(!flag)
        {

            mid.mili = high;
            mid.bake();
            printf("PLATINUM: %d:%02d:%02d:%03d" ,mid.h , mid.m,mid.s,mid.ms);
        }
    else
        {

           mid.mili = low;
            mid.bake();
            printf("PLATINUM: %d:%02d:%02d:%03d" ,mid.h , mid.m,mid.s,mid.ms);
        }

return 0;
}
```

But this seems to be too slow, i believe it can be done in better way as i think i haven't exploited the fact that `Gold` must appear between `Platinum` and `Stone` .

Or in general , **How can i improve binary search if i roughly know how far away from i am from the required value ?**

as a `Stone` is got to be farther away from `Platinum` than `Gold` is.

Comment: [Interpolation search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interpolation_search)

Comment: @timrau i am interested to know as how Interpolation search can be used in this case. Make a detailed answer please?

Comment: According to the statement "a Stone is got to be farther away from Platinum than Gold is," the next guess does not need to be `(low+high)/2`. Maybe `(2*low+high)/3`, maybe `(low+2*high)/3`. As long as there is no `Gold` nor `Stone` in code snippet, I don't know how to apply the prior knowledge either.

Comment: @timrau doesn't that would account similar to ternary search ? ,

Comment: @AntOnATree: Can you specify the game more in detail. For example, I didn't understand why you couldn't just take the minimum time, say 00:00:00:0001, as this will get you always Platinum, right? Or do you search for the *largest* Platinum time? Or alternatively, do you want a minimum number of trials? Please specify your goal more in detail.

Comment: @davidhigh sorry , made a typo. Yes i need to find the largest time for which i can get Platinum

Comment: @AntOnATree: and do you want it as fast as possible, or with as little trials as possible, or any other criterion?

Comment: @AntOnATree: and one more: what exactly is your knowledge about the problem? Is it just that there are three classes which are arbitrarily spread? If so, that isn't really something which helps you searching. What helps is if you know minimium sizes of the regions, or average positions, or some other definite numbers. Are these available?

Comment: @davidhigh with as little trials as possible , and i have mentioned all i know(or can think of) of the problem.

Answer (score 1):

If you have no idea about the distribution of the boundaries, it is like you don't know anything about your problem. Further, as there is no penalty for obtaining "stone" or "gold", you can forget about the boundary in between these two and treat the whole setup as "platinum" -- "non platinum".

Again, without an idea then where this single boundary is, you gain nothing. An "idea" here means a statistical distribution (--other than uniform, as that will lead to the usual binary half-interval search). If you have such a distribution, you probably would proceed not by simply halfing the current interval, but always make the cut at the point of its average. In both cases, with and without information, a binary search should give you the lowest number of trials on average.

Further, if one considers the version with a penalty for "stone" (say penalty=2) and "gold" (say penalty=1), and the task is also to get as little penalty while solving the problem, this reminds me of a generalized version of the egg dropping puzzle, [see Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_programming#Egg_dropping_puzzle).

Answer (score 0):

Edit:

To make it faster for PLATINUM, you have to keep low and high closer to each other. So, you can adjust both of them so that your search can conclude faster or slower as required.

For platinum, you can increase low or decrease high (by 10)

For stone, you can decrease low or increase high (by 10)

For gold, you can manipulate as same as platinum or stone but to different magnitude (by 5).

This is one idea. This magnitude you can decide on the basis of low and high value on the basis of some logic.

Comment: It is a necessity , i HAVE to print in order to know which medal i will get for the gussed time, so avoiding this is not an option

Comment: When the OP asks about improving the "speed" of binary search I don't think it's about the CPU time, but rather the number of steps in the core algorithm.  Therefore `fflush` and `printf` are irrelevant.

Comment: @JohnZwinck: Thanks. I missed important part. See edit.

Comment: @dbasic what exactly should this `magnitude` , i'm afraid that i may interfere with the correctness of the algorithm

Comment: For example, for platinum or stone, you can keep say 10% of (high-low). For gold, you can take it 5% or 7%.

Comment: Consider the case if : 
Platinum : 0:00:12:00
Gold : 0:00:12:01
Stone : 0:00:12:02

This will not give correct result

Comment: I think your binary search requires some change. From code, it seems that you are taking Platinum, Gold or stone as input. But as per your comment and problem, it looks like that it takes time and on the basis of time, you need to guess platinum, gold or stone. Correct me.

Comment: @dbasic , the Max times for Platinum, Gold and Stone are decided by the game at the begining , I guess a time, print it out , and based on the values chosen by the game at the start , i tells where i stand , do i get a Platinum, Stone or Gold .